# Can Google home be used for reminder?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

I would like to set an applet that basically does the following :

In the morning, before work, I tell "Hey Google, please remind Mary to do her homework at 5:00 PM"

Google Home answers : "You got that, I'll tell Mary to do her homework at 5:00 PM"

And at 5:00 PM, the assistant do broadcast the message: "Mary, I remind you to do your homework"

Can I do that and if yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

The Google Home does support [alarms](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7071598?hl=en-GB).

> “Set an alarm for 5 PM called Mary's homework”

Your device will then ring an alarm sound at 5 PM, as expected. However, it will not announce what alarm is ringing, according to the documentation:

> - Alarm sounds will only be played from the internal Google Home speaker and not other Cast devices (e.g. TVs, other speakers) that are associated with the Google Home device.
> - **Currently, you can't change your alarm tone.**

Hence, you currently can't get your Home to announce what you want, but an alarm is relatively close to what you're looking for, and is currently supported on the device without any additional Actions required.